# How I'm supposed to run unit test for angular ui-router

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router, karma-runner

I'm quite new with karma...
I want to contribute with a bug fixing for [angular ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router).

I need to write new unit tests and check all the other tests but I don't understand how I'm supposed to run karma on this project.

I have tried with:

```
grunt dev
```

But karma seems to be not running, I get "There is no server listening on port 8080". And in any case also if I manually run karma I see only a summary, the output is something like: "Done with errors".

So I have tried with:

```
karma start config/karma.js
```

but I don't see any output result, maybe karma reporters are not configured?

I have also tried with

```
grunt default
```

This command seems to do what I need but I should running it every time, it is not configured to autowatch.

On my projects I usually configure karma or mocha to auto watch files and I simply leave it in the background.

How do you suggest to work on ui-router project or other similar project?
Maybe I missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from their [Gruntfile](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L133) that `grunt default` will build the project and run all tests.

To kick the tests off in to watch mode you can use `grunt karma:watch`. This will run all ~280 when anything under [`src/` or `test/` changes](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/Gruntfile.js#L58)

Comment: Thanks @juco, `grunt karma:watch` is exactly what I'm looking for.